# Is there a way to spin up two hadroop HDFS clusters on the same machine?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Is there a way to spin up two hadoop HDFS clusters on the same machine?

I struggle to spin up two on my localhost because there will be a port conflict for datanode.

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to test by doing this?

Comment: I want to test writing the same data to two HDFS clusters. I was wondering if that's possible.

Comment: You would point the client at two different namenode addresses, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really possible because one `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` variable will be used for both, and so only one set of XML config files will be able to define any ports.

In theory, you could use multiple terminals and export that variable to different locations, then start all services in those terminals, but I'd recommend using a VM or Docker to remap the service port to a different host port.